# Classical algebraic geometry in infinite dimensions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I ran into [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-03/S0002-9939-1952-0047019-0/S0002-9939-1952-0047019-0.pdf) of Serge Lang, if I understood him correctly (of which I am doubtful), then since $\mathbb{C}$ has uncountable transcendence degree over its base field $\mathbb{Q}$, Hilbert's Nullstellensatz holds for $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\dots]$. That is, we can deduced from here that radical ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ are in bijective correspondence with Zariski closed sets of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$. Is this true?

> **EDIT: Related**
>   We consider a finer topology and a bigger algebra. When we are dealing with infinite dimensional vector spaces, it may be wiser to use its full dual. So instead of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots]$ what if we look at the symmetric algebra $S((\mathbb{C}^\infty)^*)$.
>
> We endow Zariski topology on $\mathbb{C}^\infty$, where closed sets are exactly the zero locus of subsets (or ideals) of $S(\mathbb(C^\infty)^*)$. Conversely for any subset of $\mathbb{C}^\infty$, associate its vanishing ideal in $S((\mathbb{C}^\infty)^*)$. Then the question is whether closed subsets of $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ corresponds to radical ideals of $S((\mathbb{C}^\infty)^*)$?